Get the langauge belonging to the given country
Using the node package: npm install countries-list, found here (where there is a bit of info on usage:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/countries-list
We have countries which gives us an object of all the countries, and we have languages which gives us an object of all the languages. I want to map languages to the correct countries.
So I get the countries like this
const countryNames = [], langs = [];
let idx = 0; 

for(const c of Object.values(countries)) {
    countryNames[idx] = <Dropdown.Item>{c.name}</Dropdown.Item>;
    // get the language of the country at countryNames[idx]
    idx++;
}

We can get the countrycode like so: getCountryCode(c.name). What would then be reasonable to do (in my head), would be something like:
langs[idx] = <Dropdown.Item>{languages[getCountryCode(c.name)].languages[0].name}</Dropdown.Item>;

But languages and countries do not share the same code. How can I go about this?

This looks like a question best asked here: https://github.com/annexare/Countries/discussions

const res = Object.values(countries).map(c => { const lang = c.languages.map(lang => languages[lang]); return {...c,languages:lang}; })

if you are only interested in the 0th language for country. languages[c.languages[0]]
